# Image.ImageUrl = ... nothing is displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

On my development system (Win 10 Pro, VS 2015), I am testing a web forms app in VS 2015; it uses a master page. An image control in an asp content page shows nothing when I try to display a photo from a file just written after a resize, whereas it displays the original photo just fine. Here is the code-behind fragment with the problem detailed in the comments:

```
    // During testing, sRelLoc contains "~/i/SlideShow/1th.jpg" (original photo)
    string sRelLocMod = sRelLoc.Replace("~/", "").Replace("/", "\\");
    // During testing, Global.sgHomeDir contains "K:\\DataAndDocs\\12_Projects\\TinyNP\\TinyNP\\"
    string sImgUrl = Global.sgHomeDir + sRelLocMod;
    // sImgUrl now contains 
    System.Drawing.Image Photo = null;
    // Read original photo from file
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sImgUrl, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        Photo= System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs);
    }
    // ResizeImage from https://www.codeproject.com/articles/191424/resizing-an-image-on-the-fly-using-net
    System.Drawing.Image PhotoResized = ResizeImage(Photo, new Size(400, 400), true);
    sImgUrl = Global.sgHomeDir + "i\\tempImg.jpg";
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sImgUrl, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        PhotoResized.Save(fs,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    // NOTE THAT: The image has been saved correctly in its resized form inside the expected directory
    sImgUrl = sImgUrl.Replace("\\", "/");
    //sImgUrl now contains "K:/DataAndDocs/12_Projects/TinyNP/TinyNP/i/tempImg.jpg"
    // Image1 is an Image control on an asp.net web page.
    // PROBLEM: The following statement displays nothing where Image1 is
    //          placed (not even a red-x or anything) , ...
    Image1.ImageUrl = sImgUrl;
    // ... but displays the unresized original just fine when the following statement is used instead:
    //          Image1.ImageUrl = sRelLoc;
```

Same behavior whether or not running in debug mode.

Perhaps there is a better approach than writing the resized photo to temporary file tempImg.jpg and then reading from it?

**Update after jignesh's and Sami's responses:**

I am using MapPath in Default.aspx.cs (see new comments below).

Now using System.Uri to convert path to Url which starts with "file:///". Leads to nothing being displayed. Replacing "file:" with "http:" leads to a broken image symbol being displayed. Updated code is:

```
    // During testing, sRelLoc contains "~/i/SlideShow/1.jpg" (original photo)
    string sRelLocMod = sRelLoc.Replace("~/", "").Replace("/", "\\");
    // During testing, Global.sgHomeDir contains "K:\\DataAndDocs\\12_Projects\\TinyNP\\TinyNP"
    //  which was obtained in Default.aspx.cs Page Load Event by
    //    Global.sgHomeDir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(null);
    string sImgPath = Global.sgHomeDir + "\\" + sRelLocMod;
    // sImgPath now contains "K:\\DataAndDocs\\12_Projects\\TinyNP\\TinyNP\\i\\SlideShow\\1.jpg"
    System.Drawing.Image Photo = null;
    // Read original photo from file
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sImgPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    { Photo= System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs); }
    // ResizeImage from https://www.codeproject.com/articles/191424/resizing-an-image-on-the-fly-using-net
    System.Drawing.Image PhotoResized = ResizeImage(Photo, new Size(400, 400), true);
    sImgPath = Global.sgHomeDir + "\\i\\tempImg.jpg";
    // sImgPath now contains "K:\\DataAndDocs\\12_Projects\\TinyNP\\TinyNP\\i\\tempImg.jpg"
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sImgPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
    { PhotoResized.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); }
    // I have verified that the image has been saved correctly in its resized form inside the expected directory
    System.Uri ImgUrl = new System.Uri(sImgPath, UriKind.Absolute);
    // Image1 is an Image control on an asp.net web page.
    string sImgUrl = ImgUrl.ToString();
    //sImgUrl now contains "file:///K:/DataAndDocs/12_Projects/TinyNP/TinyNP/i/tempImg.jpg"
    Image1.ImageUrl = sImgUrl;
    // The above statement DOES NOT work (displays nothing at all)
    // However:
    //Image1.ImageUrl = "~/i/tempImg.jpg"; // ** DOES ** work ok
    // If I replace "file:" with "http:", a broken image symbol is displayed.
```

But what does work is using a tilde "~" even though it does not look like a Url. Is it ok to use the tilde? Will it get me into any trouble, like when deploying to a hosting server?

Comment: Because a browser has no access to your disk. You have to give it a URL, not a path. Also don't do manual changes from URLs to paths, that's what `MapPath()` is there for.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ImageUrl property to specify the URL of an image to display in the Image control.You can use a relative or an absolute URL. A relative URL relates the location of the image to the location of the Web page without specifying a complete path on the server. The path is relative to the location of the Web page. This makes it easier to move the entire site to another directory on the server without updating the code. An absolute URL provides the complete path, so moving the site to another directory requires that you update the code.

By absolute url, they mean the entire IIS path to the URL (Not your disk directory path). (i.e. http://yourVirtualDirectory/ExternalImages/logo.jpg).

So here in above code sImgUrl="K:/DataAndDocs/12_Projects/TinyNP/TinyNP/i/tempImg.jpg" it should be like http://yourVirtualDirectory/tempImg.jpg